# How to send nested data in response , rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails 4. I have a two models- "Company" & "Employees". Company has_many employees. I want to fetch the company and get all the employees in its nested dictionary in API like this,

```
  {"Company":{"name":"companyName",
             "total_employees":1000000,
             "Employees":[{"name":"xyz"},
                          {"name":"abc"}]}
```

In company controller I tried

```
respond_with(Company.for(@current_user.id))
```

In company model

```
scope :for, ->(id) do
 Employee.joins(:company).where(:company_id => id).to_a
end
```

and getting this output

```
[{"name":"xyz"},{"name":"abc"}]
```

But I need company's attributes also. Please help.

Comment: Try `Employee.joins(:company).select("companies.*").where(:company_id => id).to_a`

Comment: By doing this, Each employee dictionary is having companie's attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that you need to handle in the views with a proper response builder.

While `acts_as_api` suggested by @rob works, Rails starting from v4.0 has built in support for building and sending rich JSON responses using a typical builder style DSL. It is called `jbuilder` - https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

Just like you have `.html.erb` views, you define `.json.jbuilder` views in the same directory and you are all set to create any type of JSON response.

Particular advantage with `jbuilder` over `acts_as_api` is the support for partials (similar to erb templates) and also the fact that the response logic will be in a `view` as opposed to a `model`.

P.S: I used `acts_as_api` until Rails added support for `jbuilder` views in v4.0

Answer (score 1):

you should give act_as_api a try (https://github.com/fabrik42/acts_as_api)

with this gem you can define it very easy like:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_api

  has_many :employees

  api_accessible :public do |template|
    template.add :name
    template.add :employees
  end
end
```

and

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_api
  belongs_to :company

  api_accessible :public do |template|
    template.add :name
  end
end
```

and render it in controller:

```
    companies = Company.includes(:employees).where(id:1).first

    respond_to do |format|
        format.json {render_for_api  :public, json: companies}
    end
```

result:

```
{"company":{"name":"companyName","employees":[{"name":"xyz"},{"name":"abc"}]}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort and throwing some light on act_as_api.